# Oracle PL/SQL - How to catch the bad data in a separate table in the exception clause?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, error-handling, plsqldeveloper

## Below is the code

```
declare
   cursor c_data
   is
      select * from test_product_u;
begin
   for i in c_data
   loop   
      insert into test_product_u_final
                (PRODUCT_NO, CREATED_DATE, DATE_FORMAT) 
         values (i. PRODUCT_NO, i.CREATED_DATE,i.DATE_FORMAT);
   end loop;
exception when others then
---->'I want to catch the bad data here ? What are the options apart from the sqlerror message I want the data itself possibly in a VARCHAR column'<----
end;
```

1. I want to catch the bad data in the exception clause? What are the options apart from getting the sqlerror message I want the data itself possibly in a VARCHAR column ? Is that possible.
2. What generally happens in a DW load for catching the invalid data ?

Comment: How much data are we talking about?

Comment: Lets just say 10 records for this example but for a DW nightly load would be more than 500,000 records.

Comment: Well the approach for 10 rows would be very different to that for 500,000 rows :)

Comment: What sort of errors are you trying to capture?

Comment: Any error apart which doesnt meet the data definition of the table , like NOT NULL or DATA TYPE MISMATCH. Irrespective of the error I want take a snapshot of the incoming data into the exception table.

Comment: I would have said regardless of number of rows that a simple error table with three columns....   ID (use a sequence), Data (just concatinate and comma or pipe separate and put in large Varchar or Clob depending on data size), then a varchar to store the actual error message.  Then in your exception just do an insert into this table.

Answer (score 1):

Per the code example you need to just put a BEGIN END inside LOOP to successfuly log the error in separate error table. Below i have illustrated the example. Hope this helps.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_data
  IS
    SELECT * FROM test_product_u;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN c_data
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      INSERT
      INTO test_product_u_final
        (
          PRODUCT_NO,
          CREATED_DATE,
          DATE_FORMAT
        )
        VALUES
        (
          i. PRODUCT_NO,
          i.CREATED_DATE,
          i.DATE_FORMAT
        );
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      INSERT
      INTO bad_data_tab VALUES
        (
          i.product_no
          ||';'
          ||i.created_date
          ||';'
          ||i.date_format
        );
    END;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20009,SQLERRM,TRUE);
END;
```

Comment: So the above code inserts all the rows into the bad table if there is one bad row. Can you split the loop to only push the bad rows out and good rows to actual destination?

Comment: It is doing it exactly the way you requested. Insert good rows into destination and load bad records into bad_table.

Comment: Why do this row by row (or "slow by slow" as my team says), when you can do it much faster (orders of magnitude) using set based SQL, as per my answer...

Comment: yes you are right. My intention is to make my answer as closer to OP question so that minimal changes required.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally the approach to take is to use set based processing as much as possible this will be (literally) 100x faster that a row by row approach. Most database validation can all be done using the power of set based SQL. In addition, if you have the hardware (CPU and IO bandwidth), is easy to parallelize to get even more performance.
Most DW load take a "waterfall" approach, loading from table to table until the data is finally clean. 
Taking one of your data checks as an example, NOT NULL, it can be written something like this, using a multi-table insert.

```
insert /*+ APPEND */ all
when ( col is null ) 
then
into table product_error_1 ( PRODUCT_NO, CREATED_DATE, DATE_FORMAT) values (PRODUCT_NO, CREATED_DATE, DATE_FORMAT )
else
into table product_stage_2 ( PRODUCT_NO, CREATED_DATE, DATE_FORMAT ) values ( PRODUCT_NO, CREATED_DATE, DATE_FORMAT )
select * from test_product_u
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test_product_u
(product_no varchar2(1024),
created_date varchar2(1024),
date_format varchar2(1024) default 'yyyy-mon-dd');

create table test_product_u_final
(product_no varchar2(1024),
created_date date not null,
date_format varchar2(1024) default 'yyyy-mon-dd');

insert into test_product_u(product_no, created_date)
values('A', '2017-mar-02');
insert into test_product_u(product_no, created_date)
values('B', null);
insert into test_product_u(product_no, created_date)
values('C', '28-february-2017');

commit;
```

**Method 1:**

```
begin
  dbms_errlog.create_error_log('TEST_PRODUCT_U_FINAL', 'TEST_PRODUCT_U_FINAL$ERR') ;
end;

declare
  cursor c_data is
    select * from test_product_u;
begin
  for i in c_data loop
    insert into test_product_u_final
      (product_no, created_date, date_format)
    values
      (i. product_no, i.created_date, i.date_format) log errors into test_product_u_final$err
      ('INSERT') reject limit unlimited;
  end loop;
end;
```

**Method 2:**

```
declare
  cursor c_data is
    select * from test_product_u;
begin
  for i in c_data loop
    begin
      insert into test_product_u_final
        (product_no, created_date, date_format)
      values
        (i. product_no, i.created_date, i.date_format);
    exception
      when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('========== Exception (Start) ===============');
        dbms_output.put_line('Product: ' || i.product_no);
        dbms_output.put_line('Created Date: ' || i.created_date);
        dbms_output.put_line('Date Format: ' || i.date_format);
        dbms_output.put_line('Error Code: ' || sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line('Error Text: ' || sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line('Error Trace: ' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
        dbms_output.put_line('========== Exception (End) ===============');
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```

**And output:**

```
  ========== Exception (Start) ===============
  Product: A
  Created Date: 2017-mar-02
  Date Format: yyyy-mon-dd
  Error Code: -1861
  Error Text: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
  Error Trace: ORA-06512: at line 7

  ========== Exception (End) ===============
  ========== Exception (Start) ===============
  Product: B
  Created Date: 
  Date Format: yyyy-mon-dd
  Error Code: -1400
  Error Text: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("FCI"."TEST_PRODUCT_U_FINAL"."CREATED_DATE")
  Error Trace: ORA-06512: at line 7

  ========== Exception (End) ===============
```